How to map left joined tables to generated POJO classes accurately?
Table A:

A_id
name

Table B:

B_id
fk_A_id
name

Here is the query:
Result<Record> result = ctx.select().from(A).leftJoin(B).onKey().where(condition).fetch()

If I select all the fields, join these tables, fetch the result set into Result<Record> then try to fetch the 'name' column of respective tables (record.get(A.name)), it leads to incorrect values. The value of the first occurrence of 'name' is always returned.
If I try to map the records, first into ARecord.class and then into BRecord.class, the 'name' value is still incorrect.
If I do it using the generated POJO classes, it is still incorrect, except the last occurrence overwrites the value of 'name' instead of first occurrence.
How am I then supposed to join multiple tables and fetch/map the records into my custom POJO classes then? As I am dynamically constructing my SQL queries, I can not use multiset or use maps to return the records into. I need to be able to first get Result<Record> and then map it.

You probably greatly simplified the query that is giving you wrong results. If you're using generated code to query and map results, then you wouldn't have such mapping problems. But it's hard to say from your question, as it probably doesn't reflect the actual code.
